# Google API [YouTube Data API] OAuth2 keeps returning 500 Error iOS

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

After the user authenticates for the first time, the next time we try to auth, we get a `500 Error`

I think this has to do we reusing the token, but the initial callback when the auth succeed, we don't get the `refreshToken` back, and the `access_token` expires after one hour, and we cannot issue a new one. We are using `OAuth2Swift` for the OAuth2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

500 is a Google Server Error.  You can use exponential backoff.
Check this link - https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/handle-errors